# Google Cloud Platform doesn't stop loading

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

[image]I'm experiencing an error in Google Cloud Platform.

I'm stying to start my free trial in GCP, following the step I've:

- Accepted Terms/Service conditions (Step 1)
- Verified my account through phone (Step 2)

And here the console start loading (before showing the step 3) without finishing. I just waited for 12h, so I think there is a problem.
For some other info: I'm new on the platform; I used some service like Firebase but it's the first time I go for the GCP full package.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot to show exactly where you are stuck?

Comment: yeah but is not very usefull.. I added that btw

Comment: Strange. Open an issue here: http://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: just did it.. seems like it is not an "issue" for google.

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super late, but I've just run into the same issue and strangely enough the solution for me was to upgrade on my phone rather than on my desktop

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Then after clearing the cache and disabling the ad-blocker and popup blocker, It worked. Give a try by disabling all the plugin installed in your web browser.